# how to install libmysqlclient.so.18 on nixos20.09？

Tags: nixos

I am try to install an binary software,whitch needs libmysqlclient.so.18.

But there is not libmysqlclient.so.18 on Nixos 20.09 ,but libmysqlclient.so.21

Anyone have an idea in installing or compiling the specified version of libmysqlclient on NixOS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you check the [github history](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/commits/nixos-20.09/pkgs/development/libraries/libmysqlconnectorcpp/default.nix)?

you could import it e.g. via an overlay
e.g. [version 1.1.9](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/commit/91c162e66a157fef91fa5610ababf5f425f9c469#diff-6ff93fa3d71bea2209b51a832b1ecb17b7ef69d282bd15ec8356a7bc6f09f2e5):

(other ways to find a [certain package version](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/pin-pkg-at-a-certain-version-chrome-chromedriver-version-fit/10749) in nixos )